# How to ignore some of Java's Files.lines end-of-line delimiters

Tags: java, file-io

Java's Files.lines method reads all lines from a file as a Stream, breaking the file into lines at the following delimiters:

```
\u000D followed by \u000A, CARRIAGE RETURN followed by LINE FEED
\u000A, LINE FEED
\u000D, CARRIAGE RETURN
```

I have files that contain the odd occurrence of `\u000D, CARRIAGE RETURN` which I do *not* want to treat as a new line, to be consistent with the way that grep (Windows) doesn't treat just a single `\u000D` as a newline marker. I want to process the lines in the file as a stream, but is there a way I can get a stream that doesn't use a single `\u000D` as a newline marker, using just CR/LF or LF? I have to use Java 8.

My problem is that I am getting grep to return the line number with its matches, but because of the difference in EOL delimiters, `Files.lines.skip(numLines)` doesn't then align with the same line if I try to skip to the line number returned by grep.

Comment: You will need to read the file another way; e.g. using the Reader or InputStream API to read bytes or characters and then assemble the lines yourself.  (Or not assemble lines .... if you only need to *count* them.)

Comment: Yes @StephenC, I am now reading the file into a byte[] and counting just the LFs to get to the required line.

Comment: I assume that you are not reading the entire file into a single `byte[]` ...

Comment: Yes @StephenC, I am. It's working so far with the file sizes I have to deal with. But if there's a way to handle larger files without too much code, I'm all ears.

Comment: Well ... just using a `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedReader` and reading one byte / character at a time would avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you are doing byte-wise input ...

A scalable / efficient solution avoids holding the entire file in memory, and / or creating a string object for each line of input that you skip.  This is one way to do it.

```
File f = ...
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
int lineCounter = 1;
int wantedLine = 42;
int b = 0;
while (lineCounter < wantedLine && b != -1) {
    do {
        b = is.read();
        if (b == '\n') {
            lineCount++;
        }
    } while (b != -1 && b != '\n');
}
if (lineCounter == wantedLine) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Notes:

1. I know this is a bit clunky.  And it would be possible to do away with the nested loop ... but this code is intended to be "illustrative" of an approach.
2. You could possibly get better performance by using `ByteBuffer`, but it makes the code more complicated.  (If you are unfamiliar with the `Buffer` APIs.)
3. You could do something similar with a `BufferedReader`.
4. For production quality code, you should use *try with resources* to manage the `InputStream` resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Stream.of(Files.readString(path).split("\r?\n"))
    .filter(...
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm constrained to Java 8.

Comment: Another problem is that this does not scale.  You start by reading the entire file into memory as a single string.